# onSelectRow in a JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jquery-events, jqgrid-formatter

I have gone through the solutions given for not working onSelectRow but they could not worked for me.

I have following code :

```
$("#myActions_gridTable").jqGrid({
        datatype:'local',
        data: myActionsData,
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        cellEdit: true,
        rowNum: noOfLinesToDisplay,
        pager: $("#myActions_pager"),
        sortname: 'contract_Name',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'asc',
        autoWidth:true,
        loadonce: true,
        cmTemplate: { title: false },
        height:'auto',
        scrollrows: true,
        colNames:["id","Status"],
        colModel:[
            {
                name:'id',index:'id', jsonmap:'id', width:1,hidden:true,key:true, editable:true
            },

            {name:'status',index:'status', align:'center', sortable: false,
                editable: true,
                edittype: "select",
                width: 150,
                editoptions: {
                    value: "1:Done;2:Running"
                }

            }
        ],


        onSelectRow : function(id){ 
            console.log('inside onSelectRow');
            if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                $('#myActions_gridTable').restoreRow(lastsel);
                $('#myActions_gridTable').editRow(id, true);
                lastsel = id;
            }

        }
    });
```

Here OnSelectRow does not get fired, no console.log is printed.
Please help.

Comment: It's strange that you use both `cellEdit: true` and `editRow` (inside of `onSelectRow`). Which [editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#editing) you want to implement: cell editing or row editing? Do you defined `lastsel` variable?

Comment: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events  here 'S' is in capital for variable name 'lastSel', that might be a cause. Do you find any browser console error?

Comment: i don't think it is about the variable name issue .. @BhushanKawadkar

Comment: @Oleg Nothing was working for me so I just tried adding cellEdit also true.

Comment: @p.pradnya: Could you include the *input data* which you use. I find strange that you use `edittype: "select"` with `editoptions: {value: "1:Done;2:Running"}` **without** usage of `formatter: "select"`. Do you use `"Done"` and `"Running"` strings in the input data or `1` or `2`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the variable `lastsel` as

```
 var lastsel;
```

In the above code you need to do :

```
var lastsel;
$("#myActions_gridTable").jqGrid({
..............
..............
..............,
  onSelectRow : function(id){ 
                        console.log('inside onSelectRow');
                        if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                            $('#myActions_gridTable').restoreRow(lastsel);
                            $('#myActions_gridTable').editRow(id, true);
                            lastsel = id;
                        }

                    }
```

Here is the working [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/6935/)

And  could get further info here [http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents).

Comment: I had declared the lastsel variable, so that is not the issue

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem could be the usage of `edittype: "select"` **without** usage of `formatter: "select"`. In any way the property `editoptions: { value: "1:Done;2:Running" }` seems me very suspected if you don't use `formatter: "select"`.

How looks the input data for the column `"status"`? Do you use `1` and `2` or `"Done"` and `"Running"`? If you want to hold `1` and `2` values in the data, but you want to display the values as `"Done"` and `"Running"` then you should use

```js
formatter: "select", edittype: "select", editoptions: {value: "1:Done;2:Running"}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/p.pradnya.htm) demonstrates it. It uses

```js
var myActionsData = [
        { id: 10, status: 1 },
        { id: 20, status: 2 }
    ];
```

as the input.

Alternatively one can use

```js
var myActionsData = [
        { id: 10, status: "Done" },
        { id: 20, status: "Running" }
    ];
```

but one should use

```
edittype: "select", editoptions: {value: "Done:Done;Running:Running"}
```

in the case. No [formatter: "select"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#formatter_type_select) are required in the last case: see [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/p.pradnya1.htm).

Answer (score 1):

`OnSelectrow` is not working when `cellEdit` is true.

You can use `onCellSelect` instead of `OnSelectrow`.